# iOS Using init to initialize all my values

Tags: ios, initialization, init

I need a way to initialize a lot of objects only the 1st time my app is installed. So I thought I use this:

```
    -(id) init {
    self = [super init];

       if(self) {
         NSUserDefaults *myUD = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         [myUD  setObject:@"5" forKey:@"Extra"]; // 5 giving 4 extra diaries
         [myUD  setObject:@"0" forKey:@"CatchingUp"]; // it's a live diary
         [myUD  setObject:@"888" forKey:@"SendingSuccess"];
         [myUD  synchronize];
       }
    return self;
    }
```

I obviously have many more than theses to initialize but it's just to give you the idea of what I did.

I deleted the app from my phone in order to test, but the init wasn't performed. I put it before ViewDidLoad.

What am I doing wrong please or is there a better way to do it ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you calling this `init` method like so: `[[MyViewController alloc] init]`?

Comment: I am doing exactly what you are seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to set up some values at the first time your app runs,

Put this code in app delegate and use this method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method,
or you can put this code in your view controller and use this method in viewDidLoad method:)

```
- (void)setDefaultInfoValue {
      if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"everLaunched"]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"everLaunched"];
        //put you code here
        NSUserDefaults *myUD = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [myUD  setObject:@"5" forKey:@"Extra"]; // 5 giving 4 extra diaries
        [myUD  setObject:@"0" forKey:@"CatchingUp"]; // it's a live diary
        [myUD  setObject:@"888" forKey:@"SendingSuccess"];
        [myUD  synchronize];
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. I ended up doing something like what you propose because I do need to save values to disk. It works fine now. Sorry, I wasn't allowed to vote you up :-(  Not fair !

Comment: It is fine:) Glad that it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you code will run whenever you create an instance of the class that contains the code - this is likely not what you want (and isn't what you describe).

Instead of `setObject:forKey:`, you should use `registerDefaults:` which installs the specified values only if values don't already exist and doesn't save the values to disk. This could be done in the app delegate, or separately in each class that uses different keys from user defaults.

The immediate problem you observe is probably that you aren't creating an instance of the class which contains your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Wain. I am not sure I understand. Let me tell you what I want and may be you tell me how to get it. :-)  I need a way to put some values in different keys in NSUSerDefaults. Later on, I am going to change them but to start I need them and I only need them once when the app starts or when the app is deleted and run again because of course they would reset my values if they were running each time the app runs. What is the way of doing that ?

Comment: My answer describes the way of doing that: `registerDefaults:`

Comment: But where do I include it ? In ViewDidload, in Init ?

Comment: Ok, I am going to try, but what I put in init with the NSUSerDefaults even didn't run once, that's why I find it a bit strange.

Comment: You probably aren't creating an instance of that class (as per the comment above from @Pavan)

Comment: That's true, I am not. I didn't know I needed to